# Hiding a paragraph if input is empty

Tags: php, html

I have a small function that grabs the input values from my html page and puts them through a php function that will display them in a list.  My goal is that if a field is left blank, the PHP script doesn't echo anything so that it would skip that instance entirely.  It's probably better to show you than just talk of course:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="test3.php" name="form">

<p>Please enter your name:</p>
<input type="text" name="1"></input>
<br />

<input type="text" name="2"></input>
<br />

<input type="text" name="3"></input>
<br />

<input type="text" name="4"></input>
<br />

<input type="text" name="5"></input>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subButton" tabindex="50"></input>


</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```
function callNames(){
    $body;
    for($name = 1; $name <= 6; $name++){
        if($name <= 5){
        echo "Your name is " . $_POST[$name] . ".<br />";


} 

elseif($name =? ){
    ?;
    }

else {
    echo "Your out of names!";
    }
};
}

callNames();
```

I left the elseif function blank, as I thought that is where my solution would go.  In other words, if you put in a name for everything but field 3, it would only echo "Your name is " 4 times but not leave an extra break where it would have been.  Would I not use an elseif to solve this?

Comment: Field name variables cannot start with a number, just so you know.

Comment: @MrD and/or `if(empty($_POST['field_name'])){`

Comment: Side note: "Your out of names!" should be "You're out of names!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a condition that looks for $_POST[$name] `length` > 0 or that looks for `$_POST[$name] != '';`

```
function callNames(){
    $body;
    for($name = 1; $name <= 6; $name++){
        if($name <= 5){
        if ( $_POST[$name] != '' ) {
            echo "Your name is " . $_POST[$name] . ".<br />";
        }
} 
elseif($name =? ){
    ?;
    }
else {
    echo "Your out of names!";
    }
};
}
callNames();
```

You can even merge the two conditions in one with `&&`

Comment: The if($_POST[$name] != '' worked great for me but I had to nix the your out of names Else code.  I didn't really need it in the first place.  Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :) Sure the code may be improved, i just copy-pasted your code with the variation, so it was easier for you to spot the changes :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, as Fred -ii pointed out in the comments, in PHP field names cannot start with a number, but if they could here is how you would do it:

```
function callNames(){
    $body;
    for($name = 1; $name < 6; $name++){
        if(isset($_POST[$name])){
          echo "Your name is " . $_POST[$name] . ".<br />";
        }
    }
    echo 'You are out of names!';
}
```

However, this assumes that the post variables go up sequentially until there are no more names.

If you explain what this is for, maybe someone can provide a better way to tackle the problem all together.

P.s the body variable seems unused?

Comment: What do you mean I can't use field names starting with numbers?  The code is running just fine from my live site so I don't see what the problem is.  If this is going to cause trouble down the line of course, I would like to fix that right away!

Comment: @Meehee I would recommend you to use `name`s that are more descriptive, that define better the kind of information that the $_POST variable will be storing :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function callNames(){

if ($_POST['name'] != ""){

echo "Your name is " . $_POST[$name] . ".<br />";

}

elseif($_POST['name'] == "?"){

    echo "?";

    }

else {

    echo "Your out of names!";

    }

}
```

Comment: if not then please explain more, I didn't understand what you wanted.